# How build JBoss Developer Studio from source?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, jboss, redhat

Ciao,

Anyone tried to build **JBoss Developer Studio** from the source-zip available at (requires free reqistration) 
[JDBS source-zip](https://access.redhat.com/jbossnetwork/restricted/listSoftware.html?downloadType=distributions&product=eval)
 ?

In the /build-directory, if I just do

```
  mvn clean install
```

it will complaint about missing child-projects.

So I found the comment in the pom:

```
<!-- for bootstrapping the parent and target-platform poms via Mead, we need to be able to fetch from this folder and run
    this profile (excluding all others); currently parent pom includes target-platform build too, so only need to build the parent
    mvn clean install -P parent,\!libs,\!tests,\!jmx,\!archives,\!as,\!common,\!jst,\!xulrunner,\!vpe \
    -P \!jsf,\!freemarker,\!hibernatetools,\!portlet,\!struts,\!cdi,\!birt,\!seam,\!examples \
    -P \!maven,\!ws,\!gwt,\!deltacloud,\!runtime,\!usage,\!central,\!aggregate-coverage
-->
```

and tried that mvn-command, but then it complaints:

```
  Child module .\parent\..\target-platform of .\parent\pom.xml does not exist
```

I never used Mead, and dont understand that stuff about boot-strapping and target-platform...

Anyways, what is the proper way to make this build work?

Comment: Looks like we are in the same boat..I am trying to figure this out too. Really bugs me that there is next to zero documentation for the source...I really like Red Hat, but it seems that they do not want to make it easy to use anything apart from the official release.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, no one's ever asked for it.

Building JBDS 6 is a three-step process:

- build JBoss Tools component projects from github sources (mostly just fetching sources from git, then `mvn clean install`
- build JBoss Tools aggregate site from github sources (fetch sources from https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-build-sites )
- build JBDS aggregate site + installer from SVN sources (fetch sources from SVN or use source zip)

I've opened a JIRA for this request:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-2456